# how to include subdirectories in qmake project file

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, include, subdirectory

Can someone please explain how to include sub-directories in a qmake project file?
For example, in the following, I want to include anything under the src folder and sub-folders of src folder.
Thanks

```
SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/../../common/ipcModule/ipcPubSub.cpp \
    $$PWD/../../common/util/dbMessageProcesser.cpp \
    src/ConfigManager.cpp \
    src/main.cpp
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  (I've used a master Makefile in a parent directory that 'starts' child Makefiles in subdirectories.  I can show you the details if this applies to your situation.)

Comment: I'm taking over a build that is messed up. I think the make files are some how auto generated by qmake and one complaint is that when someone adds a source file under a sub-directory of one of the directories, it is not compiled. - sorry that this is vague, I'm trying to learn this new system that I'm taking over.